# How do I disable 'Convert Java to Kotlin upon paste' in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, configuration, kotlin

When IntelliJ IDEA detects I'm pasting a piece of copied Java code into a Kotlin file, it offers me to convert the pasted Java to Kotlin. This dialog contains a 'Do not ask again next time checkbox'. I checked this box and selected 'Yes', but now I want to undo my default choice. How do I do this?

I've looked and searched in IntelliJ IDEA's preferences, but haven't found the respective checkbox. Is it actually in the settings, or can I somehow reset default checkbox selections?

Comment: To circumvent the smart paste, there's a 'Paste Simple' action in the Edit menu. This doesn't answer my question, but it solves my problem for now.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys` and somewhere down below you should find your checkbox (took me a while to find this, phew)

[image: Convert Kotlin to Java]

Comment: Wow.. This one isn't found when searching for 'java kotlin', which is something I'd expect for a string 'Convert pasted Java code to Kotlin'. Also, searches like 'convert java' and the like don't result in the Smart Keys section. Thanks for finding this.