# Android Studio force java to kotlin translation

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

When I paste java code into an Android Studio project that is in Kotlin, it automatically translates the code. However sometimes it does not do it automatically. Is there a way to tell Android Studio "hey dude, please translate this bunch of code"?

Comment: `Ctrl + Shift + Alt + K` should work, as long as you throw in a "please" too.

Comment: It does not work, with or without the "please".

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/mixing-java-and-kotlin-in-one-project.html then. Is the file you're pasting it in Kotlin, then? See this too, it's the opposite of your question but the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47984379/how-do-i-disable-convert-java-to-kotlin-upon-paste-in-intellij-idea